# Editing readonly field in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am recording web application with an readonly field in it, using **JMeter**.
I want to edit the read only field or change the value of it using jmeter and run the test case. Can this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by a read only field?  A textbox with text that can't be edited?  Something else?  JMeter records and plays back the HTTP request that is sent to the server.  Nothing in that request is "read only".  You can change whatever you want and send it.  I would suggest learning a little bit about HTTP requests and how they work. Looking at a tool called Fiddler and going through the examples may be a good place to start understanding what you can do.

Comment: Yes an textbox with text that cant be edited sam,sure i will try the fiddler tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [HTML  readonly Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) guide

> The readonly attribute can be set to keep a user from changing the value until some other conditions have been met (like selecting a checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript can remove the readonly value, and make the input field editable.

JMeter neither parses HTML nor executes JavaScript, it acts on a protocol level. So just record your use case via [JMeter HTTP Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server), determine how the input is being passed in HTTP Request (I bet it will be a POST request) and change it's value in recorded sampler.